# how to set fixed frame sizes in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, window, size, fixed

say i have a tkinter window with two separate frames that i want to fill with info, my only problem is that the frame size sets itself dynamcally. my windows size is 500 by 500 and i want the top frame to go from 0,0 to 250,250. and the bottom from 0,250 to 500,500. I think you might get the idea at this point

here is my code so far:

```
def main_game(username,password,new_u,old_u):
    Tk_window_center(500,500)
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    ##
    if new_u =="":
        pass
    else:
        new_u.pack_forget()
    if old_u =="":
        pass
    else:
        old_u.pack_forget()
    ##
    output_window_frame=Frame(root, bg="black")
    user_terminal_frame=Frame(root)
    ##
    usr_output=Label(output_window_frame)
    user_inp=Entry(user_terminal_frame)
    user_term=Label(user_terminal_frame)
    ##
    output_window_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=3,columnspan=3, sticky="NSEW")

    user_terminal_frame.grid(row=4,column=0,rowspan=3,columnspan=3, sticky="NSEW")
    user_inp.pack(side="top", fill="x")
    user_term.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
```

p.s. new_u and old_u are previous frames that activate on startup

Comment: Why do you need exact sizes! Usually its best for the gui to shrink or grow to fit its contents. What is special about 500 pixels?

Comment: @BryanOakley im making the game inside a fixxed screen and i cant have it change size dynamically. it would ruin the "immersion" im trying to create

Comment: If you have a top and a bottom frame, why is the bottom frame in row 4 rather than row 1?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `grid`, you need to give each row the same non-zero weight so that each row expands to fill half of its parent. You are putting one window in row 4 which is OK, but since you only have two items in the window it's misleading so I recommend using rows 0 and 1.

```
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

output_window_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=3,columnspan=3, sticky="NSEW")

user_terminal_frame.grid(row=1,column=0,rowspan=3,columnspan=3, sticky="NSEW")
```

Of course, if you put other things in in rows 1, 2, or 3 then your frames won't each be 250 pixels tall.

There are other ways to accomplish the same thing. You could use `pack`, and set the pack options `fill` to `"both"` and `expand` to `True`. Or, you could use place and put the top window at the x/y coordinate of 0,0 with a relative width of 1.0 and a relative height of .5, and then put the other at 250,250 again with a relative width of 1.0 and a relative height of .5